# Why clang is not able to instantiate nested variadic template with defaulted integer_sequence?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Consider an example:

```
#include <utility>

template <class... Ts>
struct pack { 
   static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};

template <class P, class = std::make_index_sequence<P::size>>
struct ipack;

template <class... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct ipack<pack<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>> { 
   static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};

template <class IP, class = std::make_index_sequence<IP::size>>
struct vpack;

template <class... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct vpack<ipack<pack<Ts...>>, std::index_sequence<Is...>> { 
   static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};

int main() {
    vpack<ipack<pack<int, int, int>>> vp;
    static_cast<void>(vp);
}
```

clang [reports](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Rbq4D7W2VKLZR4JI) a problem with:

```
prog.cc:29:39: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'vpack<ipack<pack<int, int, int>, std::__1::integer_sequence<unsigned long, 0, 1, 2> >, std::__1::integer_sequence<unsigned long, 0, 1, 2>
vpack<ipack<pack<int, int, int>>> vp;
                                  ^
```

gcc [does not share](https://wandbox.org/permlink/TvA0lhsbvaPtMe0r) clangs feelings here. Which compiler is right? Is the code above ill-formed in some way?

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your compilation error with Apple's clang, `Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.41)` -- not sure which normal version of clang this corresponds to. The compiled binary also seems to work correctly; `vp.size` from your example is equal to 3, for instance.

Comment: @jwimberley so you're saying this might be a problem with wandbox's versions of clang?

Comment: I can compile it with clang 3.8 and gcc 6.1. It does look like an compiler bug. Can you please add the flags, you compile with, so that we may be able to reproduce your bug.

Comment: I copied and pasted the compile command used by WandBox, `clang++ prog.cc -Wall -Wextra -O2 -march=native -std=c++14 -pedantic` (some settings changed from your original post but with the same compiler error). This again made no errors with Apple Clang.

Comment: Wow I actually wanted to cross check if (some other related) code worked in clang and turned to wandbox... It seems that on my workstation clang also compiles the code... Thanks!

Comment: Could this equally well be a problem with WandBox's libc++ or whatever library it uses? Perhaps the templates aren't matching to the `std::integer_sequence` defined in its library...

Comment: It's not stdlib related (@jwimberley), it's to do with Clang version; [3.8.1 compiles cleanly](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ka9TpZMqyNUmwKrI), 3.9+ doesn't. So, this is either a regression or a bugfix – the question is which. If it's the latter and a workaround is needed, [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zXB5fjKjSD968IRm)'s a simple one.

Comment: Actually the code works on Wandbox for Clang compiler 3.8.1 but breaks at Clang 3.9.1 -- so this could still be a Clang regression

Comment: @ildjarn Ah, yep, I see that now (our messages crossed).

Comment: @ildjarn Nice! In my real code integer_sequences are of different lengths, but I think it will be streightforward to apply your workaround. Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with those specializations? That is, why isn't something like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hBtVqtO86dXwcORw) sufficient?

Comment: @AndyG I wanted to do something like a 2D loop and the additional level of abstraction was to cover this transparently dependently on the first level (not linearly)...

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your error using [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/8JmnMb). Clang and gcc compile it just fine.

However, playing around with the compilers, I found that msvc doesn't like your code, because of the default parameter in `ipack`. Though, if you supply the parameter directly, it works:

```
template <class...Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct vpack<ipack<pack<Ts...>,std::index_sequence<Is...>>, std::index_sequence<Is...>> { 
   static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};
```

This change fixes your clang error as well. (I couldn't figure out how to get a link in wandbox...)

**Edit:**

There is another error msvc is pointing out, which I omitted above. `vpack` has to be constructible. However, because you just declared it (`struct vpack;`), there is no default constructor available. You can fix this by defining it, using: `struct vpack {};`. That solves the clang problem as well. (Even without the above.)

**Edit 2:**

Thinking about why you need to use `struct vpack {};` I found another flaw in your code. It can be reduced to:

```
#include <utility>

template <class... Ts>
struct pack { 
   static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};

template <class P, class = std::make_index_sequence<P::size>>
struct ipack {};

template <class... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct ipack<pack<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>> { 
   static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};

template <class IP, class = std::make_index_sequence<IP::size>>
struct vpack {};

int main() {
    vpack<ipack<pack<int, int, int>>> vp;
    static_cast<void>(vp);
}
```

The reason is, that your template specialization of `vpack` does not get instantiated, is because you are using the default argument of the primary template. (`vpack<ipack<pack<int, int, int>>>` only supplies one argument instead of the two needed by the specialization.)

You could even remove the template specialization for `ipack`, were it not for the fact, that you are implicitly using it in the `vpack` primary. (`IP::size` refers to the specialization of `ipack`.)

(I wrote a version doing that: https://godbolt.org/g/6Gbsvd )

Thus, msvc and wandboxes clang were right in refusing to compile your code. I'm not sure why it works under gcc and godbolts clang. It probably has to do something with the way default parameters are handled...

Interestingly, you can see the difference by defining `size` inside the `vpack` primary:

```
#include <utility>

template <class... Ts>
struct pack { 
   static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};

template <class P, class = std::make_index_sequence<P::size>>
struct ipack;

template <class... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct ipack<pack<Ts...>, std::index_sequence<Is...>> { 
   static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};

template <class IP, class = std::make_index_sequence<IP::size>>
struct vpack { static constexpr std::size_t size = 0; };

template <class... Ts, std::size_t... Is>
struct vpack<ipack<pack<Ts...>,std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>>, std::index_sequence<Is...>> { 
   static constexpr std::size_t size = sizeof...(Ts);
};

int main() {
    vpack<ipack<pack<int, int, int>>> vp;

    return decltype(vp)::size;
}
```

gcc and clang return `3`, but msvc returns `0`.

Comment: Codebolt's clang indeed doesn't provide the compilation error. I wonder what is the cause of wandbox problem here...

Comment: I found the problem. Your are trying to construct an object from a struct without a constructor. (See edit.) This is of course cannot be done. However, why it works in gcc and in godbolt is beyond me. This is probably some special compiler feature, which only works for empty classes...

Comment: well actually if the compiler will choose proper specialization -- the one from line 20 the object is constructable, so I'd say it isn't the underlying cause but rather the effect of it...

Comment: Hmm... One would have to lookup the exact wording in the standard. But I guess, the general case has to be constructible, because the compiler might need to construct it, even when in reality it never does.

Comment: @W.F. I made a second edit arguing why your specialization is not instantiated the way you thought ;)